# Translating from numpy to pure python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, numpy

I can't use numpy and I'm having trouble translating the following from a numpy array and placing values in specific indexes to pure python using only lists and lists methods. Any suggestions? The columns list is the index of the columns that I need to append to.

```
n = 15
board = np.array([['1'] * n] * n)

for index in zero.columns: #This is the line im having trouble with
    board[zero.columns.index(index), index] = "0"
```

Ex of zero.columns: `[0, 2, 4, 1, 9, 11, 13, 3, 12, 8, 5, 14, 6, 10, 7]`

so the output for htis with numpy would be

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

so and so forth for the `15 x 15` board.

Comment: What you want to do with this code? can you show a sample input and expected output?

Comment: Sure, one second I'll update im trying to implement the nqueens algorithm

Comment: Do you want the pure Python `board` to be a list of lists of 1 character strings? If so, you should mention that specifically in your question.

Comment: Updated didnt realize i had an extra breacket in the numpy array, and yes im trying to get that same representation without using numpy but the problem is trying to index to put the 0's in the correct locations without numpy. I just made 1's arbitraily represent the blank spots of the board without queens could have just as easily made them blank strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several gotcha when you want to translate your code from NumPy to plain python:

```
>>> board = [['1'] * n for _ in range(n)]
>>> zeros = [0, 2, 4, 1, 9, 11, 13, 3, 12, 8, 5, 14, 6, 10, 7]
>>> for row, idx in zip(board, zeros):
...   row[idx] = '0'
... 
>>> pprint.pprint(board)
[['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
 ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
 ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
 ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
 ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
 ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1'],
 ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1'],
 ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
 ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1'],
 ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
 ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
 ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0'],
 ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
 ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
 ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']]
```

The trickiest part is you need a comprehension list rather than the simplest `[['1']*n]*n` to create the initial board, as the `*` operator will in fact create duplicate references to the *same* object. But, you really need *different* rows. Here is a simple example demonstrating that issue:

```
>>> m = [['1']*3]*2
>>> m[1][2] = '0'   # I might think I changed only *one* cell
>>> m
[['1', '1', '0'], ['1', '1', '0']]
#            ^                ^
# but *two* cells appear to have changed.
>>> m[0] is m[1]
True
# because m[0] and m[1] are in fact referencing the _same_ object.
```

After that, you need to walk along the different rows and through the *zeros* index simultaneously. Here, I used [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) for that purpose.

Comment: Although it works here, I prefer not to re-use the index variable in a nested list comprehension: sometimes it's handy to be able to access the outer index in the inner list comp. You can simplify the board initialisation to `board = [['1']*n for _ in range(n)]` or `board = [[1]*n for _ in range(n)]` for the `int` version. This is safe because each inner list will be a new list.

Comment: Alternatively, initialising & setting the zeroes can be done in a single list comp: `board = [[0 if x == zeroes[y] else 1 for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)]`, but I suspect that your way is slightly faster, since it avoids the tests in the inner loop.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you for your comments. Both are perfectly right. I've updated my answer to simplify the initialization. As about the "update loop" -- as you mentioned it, plain old procedural loops with update in-place _usually_ perform better than list comprehension. But here,  I must admit that I had more understandability/readability in mind rather than performances. _"premature optimization ..."_

Comment: Yes, as I said in [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287631/4014959) readability is much more important than minor performance enhancements. As you say, a plain old `for` loop is often just as fast as, if not faster than, the equivalent list comprehension, so converting an easy-to-read `for` loop construction into a list comp can be of dubious benefit. I just gave my example above to show that it _can_ be done, but I certainly wasn't recommending it. :)